# Which PHP interface is more effecient for multithreading

Tags: php, multithreading

I am using PHP 5.x with IIS webserver. I am going to use multithreading concept. Can anyone please tell me which PHP interface is more efficient, CLI or CGI and is there any major difference between these two for query executions?

Comment: test it yourself?

Comment: CLI is not really meant to be served via a webserver. CLI means for **Command line** interface. CGI means Common **gateway** interface. The use cases are literally in the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by @apokryfos `CLI` stands for **C**ommand **L**ine **I**nterface which is used when you execute PHP from say a Terminal/Shell (like bash).

`CGI` is **C**ommon **G**ateway **I**nterface which is the interface between a web server and your application.

There are three ways you can interface PHP from a web server (ordered from slowest to fastest):

- `php-cgi` uses CGI
- `php-fastcgi` uses **Fast**CGI
- `php-fpm` also uses **Fast**CGI but is more powerful than php-fastcgi.

`php-cgi` is pretty much outdated, and only used if you need simplicity and don't really care about performance.

`php-fastcgi` is better, but you should really use `php-fpm` if you want the best performance.

Comment: Thanks @d3L for the detailed answer